# Book where non magical people are sent out of the city to a village

Tags: story-identification, books

The book was about a boy who was born with no magic in a magic run world and he somehow gets by school without getting caught by making gadgets. Then all of a sudden he decides to join a magical sport and his teams wind a game but is caught with no magic so he is taken away to a village where people without magic are sent.

Later he learns to love it but learns that the village hides a magical source of power from the city.

Comment: Roughly when would this have been published? Did you read it in English, was it a translation? What did the cover look like?

Comment: Im not sure when it was published, I read it in english and Im pretty sure it was not a translation. Im not sure what the cover looks like.

Comment: Well, at the very least, when did you read it? If you read it 20 years ago, that's two decades of new publications we don't have to browse through :)

Comment: I would say no more than 5 years ago

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Are you sure this is not **Forging the Darksword** by Margaret Weis and Tracy Hickman, Book One of the Darksword Trilogy?  [Wikipedia article here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darksword).  In this book, Joram is born Dead where magic is required to be seen as Life.  He is stolen at birth by a crazy woman who takes Joram from the land's capital to a farm village, where he is taught sleight-of-hand tricks to bluff others that he has magic.  But one day Joram is caught as being unable to use Life magic at all, his adoptive mother is killed distracting the guards, and Joram flees to the unknown edges of the kingdom called the Outlands where he meets people who use Technology, a Dead science.  In order to revenge his birth and his adoptive mother's death, Joram learns about Darkmetal, a rare ore that can absorb magic, and plans to forge a Darksword to lead a rebellion against the tyrants of Life magic.

The trilogy continues with **Doom of the Darksword**, **Triumph of the Darksword**, and a sequel entitled **Legacy of the Darksword**.

Comment: This is similar but from what i remember, the Magicians were the ones sending people to the village

Comment: And the MP didn't try to get revenge because he was enjoyed being there