# Book about a boy who doesn't have magic and anyone who doesn't have magic is banished

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm finding a book about a kid who doesn't have magic but most people do and the people who don't have magic are banished to a place outside of the city. The boy tries his best to pretend his magic by using gadgets at school but one day he joins a "soccer like sport" that's played using magic but since he can't, he plays the sport using his feet and his team starts winning but one day during a game he get caught and banished. He then meets the people who were banished and starts enjoying himself but then learns the secret that there's an important object that the leader of the magic city wants. there might have been a battle but I don't remember.

Comment: When did you read this?  Where?

Comment: If instead of "magic" the boy lacked "a pointed head", this sounds like Harry Nilsson's _The Point_.  Does the boy have a dog named Arrow?

Comment: Doesn't "already have an answer", but it's the same question, same account. If you find approval details, you can edit your older question.

Comment: Sorry, autocorrect strikes... "additional details" is what I meant to say.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like it may be the *[Darksword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darksword) Trilogy*  by Margaret Weis and Tracy Hickman as per [Book where non magical people are sent out of the city to a village](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/230209/book-where-non-magical-people-are-sent-out-of-the-city-to-a-village).

> The son of the Emperor and Empress of Merilon, and heir to the throne, Joram was born completely Dead (devoid of magical power) in a society where magic is considered life. He is left to die but a distraught woman named Anja finds him and takes him to replace her own stillborn child.
>
> Anja teaches Joram sleight-of-hand tricks and non-magical illusions to conceal the fact that he has no magic of his own. Joram's lack of magical ability is discovered and he flees to the Outland while Anja dies trying to protect him. In the wilds of the Outland, Joram joins the outlawed Technologists who are practicing the long-forbidden Mystery of Death, Technology.

The other question mentions the soccer-like game and the hidden object. I'm currently looking for quotes.

Comment: In retrospect, this is looking more like someone was asking for the same book as you are, but this may not be the right answer as it was not accepted by that querent.

Comment: Does Joram play sports? It's been a long time since I've read the series.

Comment: @raj Possibly not. I only realized after posting that the *Darksword* books were not accepted as an answer. That said, it's a valid partial answer.